# Working with Strings/Text, TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to put together a web scraper and came across with this error, which I have no idea how to amend, I was looking at errors with the same name, but don't see the similarity with mine.. I am quite new on this btw.

The code is  the following,

```
    import bs4 as bs
    from urllib import urlopen as uReq
    sauce = uReq('http://servicios.lanacion.com.ar/archivo-f11/02/2017-c30')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'html.parser')
    acumulados = soup.findAll('li',{'class':'acumulados'})
    filename = 'LaNacion.csv'
    f = open(filename,'w')

    headers = "Título, Encabezado\n"
    f.write(headers)

    for acum in acumulados:
        title =  acumulados[0].a
        encabezado = acumulados[0].p

        f.write(title.replace(',',' ') + ',' + encabezado.replace(',',' ') + '\n')
    f.close()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both `title` and `encabezado` are of the type `bs4.element.Tag`. `title.replace` is `None`.

you probably meant to do this:

```
f.write(str(title).replace(',',' ') + ',' + 
        str(encabezado).replace(',',' ') + '\n')
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks, so what I am learning is that with the ´str´ you turn into an object with the ´replace´method, right? Thanks again

Comment: yes, `str` (which calls the `__str__(self)` method on a class) returns a string object. those have a `replace` method.